# Using Stack Collection in ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety

I need to use in my asp.net project a stack collection created inside a class

```
public class ExpressionsEvaluator
{
    public Stack<ExpressionParameter> expressionParameters = new Stack<ExpressionParameter>();

    public object EvaluateExpression()
    {
        // calculate expression patamers
        expressionParameters.Push(parameter);

        // Do some functions

        // remove the last parameters
        expressionParameters.Pop();
    }
}
```

Is this approach thread safe?

Will the expressionParameters object be different for each user accessing the website?

**Use case:**

```
    public ActionResult EvaluateExpression(string expression)
    {
        try
        {
            ExpressionsEvaluator expressionEvaluator = new ExpressionsEvaluator();
            object result = expressionEvaluator.EvaluateExpression(expression);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { hasError = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this approach thread safe?

Yes, the class in itself is thread-safe. It's how you use it.

> Will the expressionParameters object be different for each user
>   accessing the website?

That depends how you use it, and where you store it. If you create an instance of it in a web-page, than it will be a total new instance for each page-request. If you create an instance but store it somewhere, than it depends how that storage works. If you use a session, than yes, each user has its own instance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume you are using .NET Framework 4.0.

The .NET 4.0 Framework introduces thread-safe collections in the System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace:
Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)

**ConcurrentBag**
      Represents a thread-safe, unordered collection of objects.

**ConcurrentDictionary**
    Represents a thread-safe collection of key-value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

**ConcurrentQueue**
    Represents a thread-safe first in-first out (FIFO) collection.

**ConcurrentStack**
    Represents a thread-safe last in-first out (LIFO) collection.

Other collections in the .NET Framework are not thread-safe by default and need to be locked for each operation:

```
lock (mySetNeedToBeLock)
{
    mySetNeedToBeLock.Add("my information in set");
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am using .NET 4.0. I don't need to allow multiple users editing the same list, i just need to make sure that they will get their own lists to edit and doesn't influence the other lists (but i think this is the default behavior, right?)

Comment: Using the new concurrent collection communicates that instances are accessed from multiple threads, which is misleading since this is not what the OP is doing. My advice: don't use concurrent collections for code that doesn't need to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on how you're going to actually use `ExpressionsEvaluator`.

As it stands now, the code does not employ any thread safety at all, so the consumers will have to, for example by [locking](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking) the access to the shared `ExpressionsEvaluator` instances.

As for your second question, you might want to read about a [session management in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)